# Passing integer parameter in PostAsync

Tags: c#, http, post, header, http-headers

There is a Get method which I am trying to change to Post

```
   [HttpGet]
   public IHttpActionResult Expiry(int id)
   {
     return Ok(_socialChorusService.Expiry(id));
   }
```

Get method is changed to Post

```
   [HttpPost]
   public IHttpActionResult Expiry([FromBody]int id)
   {
     return Ok(_socialChorusService.Expiry(id));
   }
```

When creating a request how can i pass the integer

I can do something like below from string

```
var queryString = new FormUrlEncodedContent(  new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>{new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", id.toString())});
                    apiResponse = apiClient.PostAsync(requestUri, queryString).Result;
```

But I want to pass a integer. Is it possible or just strings can be passed in the body?

Any suggestions would be appreciated ,

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you call the Get method, the id value is transferred to the server also as a string http.//example.com/foo/expiry/42

Comment: thanks for the answer. How can i make it work?

Comment: Your comment makes me feel you did not understand my comment at all. When make a call to a WebServer then there is only text, anything is a string and the WebServer will convert from string to integer for the GET and the POST if needed and possible

Comment: Why only `[FromBody]`, you can do it in url Query String, passing only integer

Comment: because its a post request

Comment: What does that mean, `FromUri` will help in achieving what you are exactly what you are expecting

Comment: @MrinalKamboj the requirement to change the method to Post and remove parameters from URL and pass it to the body of the https post message. for security reasons

Comment: Ok you have just now specified that requirement, which is not feasible, as I have mentioned in my answer with a valid reason

Comment: @MrinalKamboj yes i checked your answer but i want to do it via body of the post message

Comment: Check the Edited version of the answer, I have provided an option to achieve what you are expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the following API:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Test")]
    public async Task<string> Test([FromUri]int value)
    {
        var result = "Done";

        if (value > 5)
            result = "Well Done";

        return await Task.FromResult(result);
    }
```

It can be called as follows and would work as expected:

`http://<ServerUrl>/api/Test?value=10`

What you are expecting is:

`public async Task<string> Test([FromBody]int value)`

This will not work, since `"value":10` is an invalid Json and valid Json is `{"value":10}`, which simply means that `value` needs to be contained in a class to be used like this

---

### Edit 1:

We can make some changes to achieve, what you are expecting, let's keep the api as:

`public async Task<string> Test([FromBody]int value)`

The post call would be:

`http://<ServerUrl>/api/Test`

In the Body of the call you will just pass `10 or 15` or whatever value you want to fill in the parameter, since that's a valid Json or in case array it would be `[10,15,20]`, which can be collected into `([FromBody]int[] value)`

Only drawback would be, you cannot thus pass multiple values in the Body, as there's no root / container object

---

### Edit 2:

Use the following client for calling the API and fetching the result:

```
async Task Main()
{
     // Input Value
     int input = 100;

     // Json Serialize the Input
     string jsonInput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);

     // Execute Api call Async
     var httpResponseMessage = await MakeApiCall(jsonInput, 
                                       "api/Test","http://localhost:59728/");

     // Process string[] and Fetch final result
     var result = await FetchJsonResult<string>(httpResponseMessage);

    // Print Result
    result.Dump();
}

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeApiCall(string jsonInput,
                                                    string api,
                                                    string host)

{
    // Create HttpClient
    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(host) };

    // Assign default header (Json Serialization)
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // Add String Content
    var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonInput);

    // Assign Content Type Header
    stringContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    // Make an API call and receive HttpResponseMessage
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;

    responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(api, stringContent);   

    return responseMessage;
}

private async Task<T> FetchJsonResult<T>(HttpResponseMessage result)
{
    // Convert the HttpResponseMessage to Byte[]
    var resultArray = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Deserialize the Json string into type using JsonConvert
    var final = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultArray);

    return final;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the requirement is to pass it to the body of the https post message. for security reasons

Comment: Will not be feasible as I have suggested, since the syntax needs container / root object for the integer value

Comment: ok thats fine. Thanks for the answer but I wanted to do via body and this is the requirement. I will think something else or wait for other suggestions. Thanks again

Comment: Check the **Edit 1**, I have provided a way to achieve it, you can simply pass the value as 10 or 15 and it will fill in  the relevant object, as you expect

Comment: thanks for the update but how can I pass int like apiClient.PostAsync(requestUri, [15]).Result; ?  but this is an array and I only have single integer value

Comment: which Rest API client are you using ?

Comment: httpclient and using postasync please check my question. The request code is there as well

Comment: Check **Edit 2**, it has the client to access the API and fetch the result as expected

Comment: You have to just modify the `Result` type to `IHttpActionResult` instead of `string` that I am using, which is for convenience. Something like, `FetchJsonResult<IHttpActionResult>` also APIs shall be better made `Async`, since they integrate Asynchronous processing seamlessly and it helps in making system much more scalable and responsive

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but still I dont get it. The method is public IHttpActionResult Expiry([FromBody]int id) and expecting an integer but you are passing the string content. I think you misunderstood the question. I wanted to ask if there is a way to pass integer in the post body request.

Comment: @OwaisAhmed I haven't misunderstood question, you need to read a bit more about Rest API, I have given you exact code, which would work as expected. For Rest API you need serialization to pass data, standard is Json, which we are using or byte[] using serializer like protobuf, which then deserialized into relevant type when received by WebAPI, Json is auto plugged, other serializers need explicit plugging. It also pass the result in serialized format, which is then de-serialized, which we are doing, this is the only way to do the communication with Rest API

Comment: I have got exactly your example to work using my code, you are returning, `Ok(_socialChorusService.Expiry(id))`, now depending on what is the return value of the `_socialChorusService.Expiry(id)`, you can use the same type while calling `FetchJsonResult`, I am using `string`, since I am returning `Ok("Super Done")` or `Ok("Done")` depending on the logic. I cannot make it simpler for you if you cannot understand even this much, I am certain even Async - Await would be confusion for you, but that means you need to learn these concepts, so that you can understand the answers